# Word 2010: How to reference custom document properties?

Tags: documents, microsoft-word-2010, properties

Using Word 2010, I've added a custom property to my document, `Something`, and I've set the value to `XYZ`. In the document, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a reference, and I type `{ DOCPROPERTY [Something] }`. When I go to print preview, the page is blank, and returning to my document, I find my reference is now gone.

What is the proper way to insert a reference to a document property?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try it without the square brackets, i.e.

```
{ DOCPROPERTY Something }
```

Press F9 after you type the field name, and it should update correctly to your field value.

Comment: Okay, that helped - the value shows up and it stays there now. But when I change the value in the Advanced Properties dialog, the references in the document retain the old value.

Comment: After you change the value in Advanced Properties, you need to select the field and press F9 to update the field value (there are a few other times Word will do this automatically - such as when you print).