# Reference DOCPROPERTY with a blank space in its Name

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

I am struggling to reference a custom document property (`DOCPROPERTY`) with a space in the name, `Blank Page`.

This Question shows how to reference a document property : [Word 2010: How to reference custom document properties?](https://superuser.com/questions/285256/word-2010-how-to-reference-custom-document-properties)  However, I have a `DOCPROPERTY` with the name `Blank Page` - how can I reference this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `{DOCPROPERTY "Blank Page"}`

The `"` around the Name escapes the '' character.

Comment: For the sake of improving your answers, SU is looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. If you have a source reference, please link it.

Comment: Whilst I generally agree with this notion I believe that this is an appropriately brief answer — a simple solution to a simple problem that simply fills a gap in documentation. I prefer a concise answer to a verbose answer where additional words would not add value. Please feel free to edit the answer if you have a useful addition.