# Microsoft Word: Create a list of policies that automatically displays the date they were amended

Tags: microsoft-word, automatic-update, cross-reference

I am trying to organise an organisations's policies and procedures, and I would like to create a master list of the policies that would automatically show the date each policy was last amended.  Is it possible to refer to another document's properties within a Word document?

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/285256/word-2010-how-to-reference-custom-document-properties

Comment: Looking at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25.aspx) article it should be possible but would involve writing your own macros into Word or Excel. Are you comfortable with that?

Comment: I'm fairly comfortable with macros and VB, but I'm afraid I don't see from the article you reference how to refer to the properties of another document.

Comment: Combining [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.path.aspx) with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.documentproperties.aspx) should get you on your way